# Equivalent formulas and equivalent statements in logic.

Tags: logic

I am reading a book titled "How to prove it", and I am learning about equivalences. I could be completely wrong here, so thanks for the patience and the help.

From the book, the absorption law looks like this:

Absorption law:

P ∨ (P ∧ Q) is equivalent to P.

---

**My question regarding this.**

Say I have two statements:

P: It is dark.

Q: It is cold.

P ∨ (P ∧ Q) would mean:

> It is either dark, or dark and cold, or both.

Which seems different from simply P:

> It is dark.

Equivalent seems to mean the following here:

The validity of the original statement (P ∨ (P ∧ Q)) depends on P alone, all other parts of the statement (like Q) don't change the validity.

And I would add, that by applying the absorption law, the resulting (simplified) form shouldn't be mistaken for having the same meaning as the original statement.

However, this seems to be a bit different in case of other equivalences:

¬¬P is equivalent to P in a sense that it is a different (simplified) form, without loosing the meaning of the original statement.

Or in case of De Morgan's law:

¬(P ∧ Q) is equivalent to ¬P ∨ ¬Q. The latter from still produces a statement that can be interpreted as having the same meaning:

> It is not both dark and cold.

And

> It is either not dark, or not cold, or neither dark nor cold.

Is it the case, that some laws or modifications can be used to simplify statements, whereas some can only be used to analyze certain relationships within the original statement?

Comment: A statement is either true or false. And if two statements produce the same result when taking the same inputs, then they are logically equivalent, no matter what information is contained in the statement.

Comment: I'm not sure about your premise. To me, "it is dark" and "it is dark, or dark and cold, or both" seem to have exactly the same content.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I am thinking, that according to the second statement, it is possible, that it is cold. Whereas the first statement ("it is dark"), doesn't have information about whether it is cold.

Comment: If I tell you "it is dark", isn't it possible that it is cold?

Comment: @AlexKruckman The statement "it is dark, or dark and cold, or both" includes the concept of cold. We know that according to the statement, it could be cold. "it is dark" does not include the concept of cold, and we don't know anything about it, we don't know if it could be cold or not, maybe it is never cold.

Comment: "It is dark, or dark and the moon is made of cheese, or both" is true whenever it is dark. Mentioning the concept of the moon being made of cheese does not suggest that the moon might be made of cheese (feel free to substitute any proposition that is never true for "the moon is made of cheese" in this example).

Comment: @AlexKruckman I think what was confusing for me, is that some information may be left implicit in a statement, after applying certain laws. I was completely wrong in my previous comment, too, as I got carried away by my intuitions from ordinary language (as you pointed out in your answer). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"$\varphi$ is logically equivalent to $\psi$" means that in any model, $\varphi$ is true if and only if $\psi$ is true. In the case of propositional logic, a model is just an assignment of a truth value to each basic proposition (i.e. a row of a truth table).

In the case of $P$ and $P\lor(P \land Q)$, it is easy to check that these are logically equivalent. If $P$ is true, then by the meaning of $\lor$, $P\lor (P\land Q)$ is true. If $P$ is false, then $(P\land Q)$ is false by the meaning of $\land$. Since also $P$ is false, $P\lor (P\land Q)$ is false by the meaning of $\lor$. We've shown that $P\lor (P\land Q)$ is true whenever $P$ is true and false whenever $P$ is false, so they are logically equivalent.

You should try to avoid allowing intuitions from ordinary language to creep into your understanding of logical words in mathematics. Words like "and", "or", "implies", and "equivalent" all have precise meanings in mathematics, which do not always match the informal and imprecise ways we use these words in ordinary language.